# ipython notebook doesn't work on ipython 2.2.0

Tags: python, ipython

I tried to run IPython notebook. I entered following in the commandline:

ipython notebook

I get the that error (stack trace)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(start_ipython())
File  "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 563, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 381, in initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 92, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 406, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 40, in <module>
check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 2.1.11
```

I'm using python 2.7.8
and iphython 2.2.0

Comment: Have you installed `libzmq` with `brew`? Have you installed `pyzmq`? I installed Python 2.7.8 and iPython 2.2.0 yesterday with brew with no issues.

Comment: yes i installed pyzmq but libzmq by

Comment: yes i installed pyzmq but libzmq by
 `brew install libzmq`
i get the following answer
 `No available formula for libzmq `

Comment: i solved the problem by install `anaconda 2.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to install newest pyzmq version by pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pyzmq
```